# How to make my e-mail public/visible in my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I just want to make my e-mail address public so that people can communicate with me if they want to, but I find no option to make my e-mail public. I tried the edit menu there I can change my display name, real name, e-mail, etc., but can't make my e-mail public. What to do?

Comment: copy it into your [about me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/257685) section?

Comment: Yeah,I just did that..Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email field is a private information of user profile. Except moderator, SE developer & OP nobody can see it.

If you want to share your email you can write it in "about me" section of your profile. I have done same, you can check my profile page.

Comment: Yeah,I got the idea.Thanks for help.